# flatmap with two columns

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Dstream twitter example -- flatmap twitter_id with text

New to scala and spark streaming.  Trying to extend example twitter stream code to split the tweet into words but keep those words connected to the twitter ids.

```
setupLogging()

val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.getText())
val tweetwords = statuses.flatmap((tweetText => tweetText.split(" ")

tweetwords.print
//get running list of words from tweets. 
This
is 
my 
tweet
"#mytweet"

//instead want the same list with an twitter_id attached
val statuses = tweetmap{status => (status.getUser().getID(), status.getText())}
val tweetwords = statuses.flatmap( ????? This is where I am lost )

//this is what I want
tweetwords.print

1523523, This
1523523, is
1523523, my
1523523, tweet
1523523, #mytweet
```

I'm open to other ways of doing this including dataframes/datasets..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looks for this...

```
val tweetwords = statuses.flatmap(case (t1, t2) => t2.split(" ").map((t1, _))}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the parenthesis in your solution...
Anyway, if your statuses was a key-value RDD, it should have been as easy as just using the flatMapValues function